# How to add additional compile flags

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, beagleboard, cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the ARM build of the PCL_ROS package to work I need to add some additional compiler (gcc / g++) flags. What is the right way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9178/how-to-add-additional-compile-flags/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-02-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [rosbuild/CmakeLists](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists) docs.

In particular, the `rosbuild_add_compile_flags` and `rosbuild_remove_compile_flags` macros are likely what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-24**:
Did you try `-finline-limit=600`?

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-02-23**:
I'm trying to add flag "-finline-limit 600" to the target pcl_ros_features in the package pcl_ros. So I added a line rosbuild_add_compile_flags(pcl_ros_features -finline-limit 600) in pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt, but I keep getting errors. I've tried adding ", leaving space out but no success. Any clues?

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-02-23**:
@Eric: I rather like marking favorite answers myself in my own questions. But of course, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ROS_ROOT/core/rosbuild/rosconfig.cmake is where ros configuration starts. There are three places ros looks for rosconfig.cmake, and if you parse rosbuild's rosconfig.cmake, you'll find it essentially does the following:

- $ROS_ROOT/rosconfig.cmake - this is the user (global) configuration file.
- /rosconfig.cmake - overrides the user's configuration file for a single package.

If neither of the above are found, or not all configuration variables are set:

- rosbuild/rosconfig.cmake finally sets some sane defaults.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1